# Verify that the vector field $\vec{V}(x,y,z)$ = $\frac{y\vec{i}-x\vec{j}}{x^2+y^2}$ is irrotational when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

By definition a vector field is irrotational when $curl(\vec{V}) = 0$.

If we take $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, say $(x,y) = (1,1)$, Then $\vec{V}(x,y,z) = \frac{yi}{2} - \frac{x}{2}j +0k$

Then, $\Delta \times \vec{V}$

$= (\vec V_{z,y} - \vec V_{y, z})\vec i +  (\vec V_{x, z} - \vec V_{z, x})\vec j +  (\vec V_{y, x} - \vec V_{x, y})\vec k = -4\vec k \ne 0; \tag 3$

Therefore it is not irrotational. But it's supposed to be! So how can I show that it is?

Comment: You are not allowed to substitute $x=y=1$ in the denominator before you take the derivative.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try and see what I get

Comment: @Andrei is right. Also keep in mind that the curl of a constant vector field is zero because curl is really about what's happening locally to the vector field. If you plug in values for $x$ and $y$, you're always going to get a curl of $0$, so that should tip you off that you've done something wrong.

Comment: If we don't substitute $x=y=1$ then we will still end up with $k=-1$ because $\frac{d}{dx} \times \frac{-x}{x^2+y^2} = 1$ and $frac{d}{dy} \times \frac{y}{x^2+y+2} = -1. So the curl is in fact 0 no matter what value you plug in.

Comment: It cancels out and you will end up with zero

Answer (score 1):

$\vec V=\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2}{\hat{\imath}}-\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}{\hat{\jmath}}+0{\hat{k}}, (x,y)\ne (0,0)$.
\begin{align}
\vec\nabla \times\vec V&=\begin{vmatrix}
{\hat{\imath}} & {\hat{\jmath}} & {\hat{k}} \\ 
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2} & -\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2} & 0
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=0{\hat{\imath}}+0{\hat{\jmath}}+\{-\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{2x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\}{\hat{k}}\\
&=\vec 0
\end{align}
So $\vec V$ is irrotational.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can compute ${\rm curl}({\bf v})$ right away, and obtain $\equiv{\bf 0}$. In fact your field
$${\bf v}(x,y,z):=\left({y\over x^2+y^2}, {-x\over x^2+y^2},0\right)$$
is the gradient field of the "function"
$$f(x,y,z):=-\,{\rm polar\ angle\ of}\,(x,y)\ .$$
This "polar angle" is not globally defined on ${\mathbb R}^2\setminus\{{\bf 0}\}$, but its gradient is.